# How to stress the subject in a question beginning with "why"?

Tags: stress, emphasis

English isn't my native language, so my question might seem dumb to you, but I wanna be sure.

I'm writing some fiction, but I have some problems with syntax...
Here's the question at issue : "why is this guy my brother and not Ed...?"
The context : the speaker is annoyed by her brother behavior (named "Sven"), and love the personnality of the "Ed" guy. So I would like to say, or stress, that she would prefer have Ed as a brother rather than Sven. I don't even know if this type of question is relevant.

I hope you understand what I'm asking... Sorry if it's something really silly!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't apologise. Your English is better than most native speakers in my English home town already, plus you're trying to make your readers' experience better for their benefit. Go you!!

I think you could use any of the following options, depending on your opinion on use of font to alter meaning;

"Why is this guy my brother, and not Ed?"
" Why is THIS/*this* guy my brother, and not Ed?"

If it were me, my preference would be to write "Why couldn't Ed be my brother, instead of this guy?". Sounds much more plaintive; I bet lots of people with annoying siblings can relate...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and your kindness! :)